# Make generic view that align subviews properly as added swift

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uistackview

I've been struggling to figure this out. In my app, my users can advertise their channels by adding social network addresses to their account. During viewDidLoad() I download user data and determine which social network button should be shown for this respective account. All the different buttons such as Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Pinterest add website should be side by side, however, if the user does not have entered a specific URL that respective button should not be shown. So I'm looking for a behavior like this:

If only 1 button(fx website button) then the website button should be centered in the view. If the user has two button then the view should distribute the two views side by side around the center. And so forth for the third, fourth and fifth button. I thought I could use a UIStackview, to add the first button and have it centered but the UIStackView stretch a single view and if there are two buttons in my UIStackView the are not aligned around center instead they have lots of spacing. Thanks a lot to anyone who has any idea of how to accomplish this.

I guess a parallel could be drawn to the game Heartstone to anyone who has experienced it or want to get a visual idea of what I am thinking. When a minion is dropped on the board it aligns with minions already there.

Edit* Added picture for visibillity:
[image]

Trials: 
I have now followed your advice and set the stackview to the appropriate alignment and distribution, and image aspect fit including the overall constraints. The result is far better but, but the spacing is huge they should hug with little spacing around center and large spacing to the sides see img:

overall constraints:
[image]

[image]

Kinds regards,

Comment: I get an overall info what you want to do, can you add some pictures to that.

Comment: @AbdulKarim i have added a picture i made fast i sketch. Sorry for bad graphics. But the idea is, that if only one btn should be shown that it should be centered, if two they should have 10 pixel spacing and centered together around center. If 3 btns then the middle should be completely centered and the left and right btn 10 pixels to the middle one and so forth.

Comment: you want it on the following formate right, and how you are currently getting

Comment: @AbdulKarim i'm not sure of what you are asking, sorry. If you are asking wether is should look like the picture, then yes :P

Comment: check the height and width of all the icons (ie should be equal ) and set the UIStackView property to Alignment - Fill, Distribution - Fill Equally, and image content mode to - aspectFit or center according to your convenience

Comment: @AbdulKarim i have tried to accomplish your advice, i have added to pictures, do you get the same result they should be centered around the middle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157980/discussion-between-abdul-karim-and-ulrik-s).

Answer (score 1):

Can be achived by following:

- use stack view
- fill equally
- constant width to at least one item
- stackview should allign center Horizontally in container with no leeding and trailing constraints
- stackview should have fixed bottom constarint

[image]

Cheer

Comment: i have tried to follow your advice allthough the result is still not what i was going for, do you get the same result am i doing something wrong. They should have been centered around the middle.

Comment: sorry it should be center Horizontally in container

Comment: hello. Thanks for the comment, i wasn't able to replicate your suggestion. I went for a normal UIView and made an algorithm instead so that layout fits perfectly, it took some hours to perfect it though. But nevertheless i have the algorithm for future use ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIStackView and set property of "Equal Equally" may work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this still stretch the btn if there is only one

Comment: For that use autolayout constraints.

give allingment to UIStackView and height and width constraints to Buttons. it will adjust.